# Can Visual Studio Command Window 2010 commands be executed in a script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, command-window

I've just learned about Visual Studio 2010's [Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx), and am hoping it might be able to automate a short set of tedious steps.

**Is it possible to put several Command Window commands into a file and execute them?**

The scenario I have in mind is:

- open a particular source file (hard-coded path is known)
- set a breakpoint at a particular (fixed) line number in that file

I want to be able to do this easily in a given, open solution - without having to go to the line number by hand, and set the breakpoint by hand.

(The line is the point where a null smart-pointer is dereferenced, and so is a very common location for breakpoints.)

**Edit - possible alternatives**

- [Recording a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kyhdt1z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - I almost mentioned in the original post that I'd considered a macro, but I was wanting to version-control the commands, and macros are binary files, so not amenable to version control
- [Creating an add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - Creating source-code and a DLL, to run some simple commands seems unnecessarily complex to me.

Comment: Have you considered creating a Visual Studio [addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [recording a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kyhdt1z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Blachshma Thank you for the comment. My reply got a bit long, so I added it to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 and newer provide a built-in mechanism to answer the specific scenario in the question, namely a way to easily set a break-point in a specific line in a specific file.

The mechanism is well-written up in [VS 2010 Debugger Improvements (BreakPoints, DataTips, Import/Export)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx).

This screenshot whose VS 2010 exporting breakpoints to XML files – which you can then share with another developer, or re-load later:

[image]

There is also a corresponding "Import breakpoints from a file" button.